# Redirect one php page to an html page in Apache htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect .php page to an .html page. Example like http://localhost/contacts.php needs to be redirected to http://localhost/contacts.html in Apache htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect 301 /contacts.php /contacts.html
```

Comment: Thank you Pedro but Hostgator claim can't redirect php to html using redirect.

Comment: [I doubt that...](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/url-redirect-methods-forwarders#htax)

Comment: iI couldn't see any mention to hostgator in the question.